# Emacs, bind "convert buffer to dos format" to f11 key

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm attempting to bind this series of commands

```
C-x RET f undecided-dos
```

to my keyboard <kbd>f11</kbd> key.  So far I've tried many things such as

```
\C-x RET \f undecided-dos
```

in my .emacs file but no success.  Please show me the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can complete a command interactively, you can then query Emacs for what the function you performed is called.  Try `M-x repat-complex-command` and press the up arrow once (or more times if you have completed other commands in the interim) or ask for key binding help:

> <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd>
>
> => `set-buffer-file-coding-system`

Unfortunately, you can't bind this directly to a keystroke:

```
;;;; BROKEN
(global-set-key (kbd "<f11>") '(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'dos-undecided))
```

... because when you try to run that, you run into

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, (set-buffer-file-coding-system (quote dos-undecided))
```

You can work around that by specifying an `interactive` form around it:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f11>")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive "*")
    (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'undecided-dos)))
```

The `"*"` argument to `interactive` says it is only allowed in buffers that you have permission to modify.